# Log stack traces in prod mode with Play applications

Tags: logging, playframework

When a Play application encounters a 500 error while running in Production mode, it will log the error like so:

```
[TIMESTAMP]: @[errorid]
[TIMESTAMP]: Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /path-to-request
[TIMESTAMP]: Execution exception (In /app/controllers/Controller.java around line 55)
```

No stack trace is included. Is it possible to configure Play so that stack trace is logged?

Bonus question: is it possible to limit the size of stack traces in logs to, say, 20 lines each to prevent runaway log growth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't limit the output of the log by default, but you can set a log4j.properties and add a file-based log.

On the error, the log itself says the reason: (In /app/controllers/Controller.java around line 55). If you are in development mode and try to access that URL you'll get a report with the error.

I assume you replaced the real path with "/path-to-request". If not probably that's the reason, that path may not exist at all in your routes file.

Comment: I am not trying to debug any particular issue here. I just want the logs to include the stack tace. Limiting the stack size would be a nice bonus, but the real issue is stack trace logging, is that possible?

Comment: Well, I'm sure in my environment I see the stacktrace of the errors, and the detailed error information on screen when the browser request fails, so it may be something in your local configuration/plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any limitations to the log, which depends on the PROD-Mode. I would recommend to debug the error and look in the code of the framework.